# Asking for an input file until it is correct in c++

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to read a file in c++. I ask the filename to user, if file exists i open it but if it does not exist i keep asking until a valid filename is entered. But when user enters a wrong file first, even though it enters a valid filename after that my program recognizes it as false. Here is my code:

```
ifstream input;
string filename;
cout<<"Enter the file name";
cin>>filename;
input.open(filename.c_str());
while(input.fail())
{
    cout<<"Incorrect filename, please enter again";
    cin>>filename;
    input.open(filename.c_str());
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear the input when it is entered wrong. Try this:

```
 ifstream input;
string filename;
cout<<"Enter the file name";
cin>>filename;
input.open(filename.c_str());
while(input.fail())
{
    input.clear();
    cout<<"Incorrect filename, please enter again";
    cin>>filename;
    input.open(filename.c_str());
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that `clear()` doesn't really clear the input but simply removes the error bit for the stream.